# Can two different data blocks have the same CRC

Tags: crc, integrity

Is it possible (even if very low possibility) to have two different data blocks (each 4K for example), and when calculating the CRC, they are found to match ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there will be conflicts. The number of possible combinations for 4K block would be 2<sup>4096</sup> * 2<sup>8</sup>. The number of possible combinations for 32-bit CRC would be 2<sup>32</sup>. So on average, 2<sup>4072</sup> different arrangements of bits in the 4K block will map to the same CRC number. Though the chance that you take two 4K blocks containing random data and they have a CRC match for 32-bit CRC is 2<sup>-32</sup> i.e. a quarter of a billion.